# Checkbox input remains false on form submit

Tags: forms, post, asp.net-core, checkbox

I am trying to `post a form` and even though all the `inputs` map their value accordingly in the receiving `controller`-method , the `bool`-s of checkbox-es remain `false`.
What am i doing wrong ?

**POCO**

```
class MyPoco
{ 
   public string User{get;set;}
   public bool Require {get;set;}
}
```

**Form**

```
<form id="createForm" method="post" action="[some url]">

<input type="checkbox" id="require" name="Require" />

<input type="text" id="user" name="User"/>

</form>
```

**Controller** (method)

```
 [HttpPost]
 [Route("[some url]")]
 public async Task<long> CreateAsync(MyPoco request)
 {

 }
```

Why in my case above  does `request.Require` is always false.I have mapped them correctly (the `name` attribute).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that you forget to set value of checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="require" name="Require" value="true" />
```

If a checkbox is checked, then the postback values will contain a key-value pair of the form [InputName]=[InputValue]

If a checkbox is not checked, then the posted form contains no reference to the checkbox at all.

Answer (score 2):

I see you are missing `asp-for` attribute for your checkbox input. Instead of `name="Require"`, use `asp-for="Require"` as follows:

```
@model MyPoco

<input asp-for="Require" type="checkbox" id="require"  />
```

If you don't want to use `asp-for` attribute then you have to use `jQuery` as follows:

```
$(document).on('change','#require',function() { 
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).val(true) 
    } else {
        $(this).val(false) 
     }
});
```

Comment: Your answer indeed works too but i  prefer not to use `jquery` .

Comment: As you are in ASP.NET Core, So best option is to use `asp-for="Require"`